# Removing DBRef from document

Tags: mongodb, morphia, nosql

I have entity Group

```
@Entity("Group")
public class Group implements Serializable{
@Id
public ObjectId id;
public String name;
public List<Students> studentsList;
}
```

and entity Student

```
@Entity("Student")
public class Studentimplements Serializable{
@Id
public ObjectId id;
public String name;
public String surname;
}
```

How to correct remove Student from Group? 
I tried something like that:

```
public void deleteStudent(String groupId, Student student) {
Group group = dataStore().find(Group.class,"_id",new ObjectId(groupId)).get();
List<Students> studentList = group.getStudentList();
studentList.remove(student);
dataStore().save(group); //doesn't work
dataStore().merge(group); //doesn't work
dataStore().delete(student); //works but causes issue cause DBref in Group still exists
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't ``save(group)`` work? 1) Is the student still in the list afterwards? 2) Are you sure your ``remove(student)`` works as expected?

Comment: Save(group) doesn't work because after performed operations I checked document with MongoExplorer and saw that dbRef in group still exists. I think remove(student) works as it should cause it deletes student from "Student" collection. As far as I know morphia doesn't support cascade or something like that. That's why dbRef in group document lefts.

Comment: There is no cascading delete. So you need to manually remove the reference from the list / collection. Using ``list.remove(xxx)`` and ``datastore.save(entity)`` should work in general. Can you debug the code in your IDE and check if the Java code really removes the student reference?

Comment: Checked it now. You were right. Java don't remove student reference from list. Operation list.remove(dbRef) doesn't work at all.

Comment: Good. I've added the comment as an answer. Feel free to update the question if you run into any other issues. As soon as the remove works in Java, the MongoDB save should do what you want.

Comment: Thank you. Obviously objectID should be comparing by "equal" method not by "==". (I add a for loop to list all students in list). It is very inconvenient that also Morphia doesn't provide cascading. Maybe you know any other wrapper which can do that? Thank's in advance!

Comment: It should be doable since Morphia knows where each entity is being referenced and could then try to find such "loose" ends. However, this adds quite some overhead for entities which are being referenced often and it would need a lot of testing to avoid any nasty bugs. You might want to raise an issue at https://github.com/jmkgreen/morphia/issues to push this further...

Answer (score 1):

There is no cascading delete in MongoDB.

You need to manually remove the reference from the list / collection. Using `list.remove(xxx)` and `datastore.save(entity)` should work in general. Can you debug the code in your IDE and check if the Java code really removes the student reference?

Once this works, the save in MongoDB should work as well.

Comment: What do you mean by cascading here? If `studentList` is the field of Group, then `studentList.remove(student)` should work if student is actually there. Especially since he saves the group object; Morphia will convert the List to corresponding JSON during save.

Comment: Cascading as in relational databases: A row in table X has a foreign key relationship to a row in table Y. If the FK is set with on delete cascade, deleting the row in table X will also delete the referenced key in Y. This concept does not exist in MongoDB with DBRefs, which are basically a convention for FKs implemented by most drivers

Answer (score 0):

This definitely should work (I use it very frequently).

I can think of a few causes:

1. your `getStudentList()` method is returning a copy of the collection,
   rather than the underlying connection.
2. you don't have an accurate `hashCode()` and `equals()` defined for the Student class and so the remove isn't matching your Group object.
3. you have a pre-loaded version of the Group object elsewhere in memory, which you are saving after `deleteStudent` is run, this rewriting an old version of the studentList with that old student still there.